# Gamil Imap messages number is exist the maximum

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I tried to pull emails from my `Gmail` by using `IMAP`, but I got a warning message like this:

> Unknown: Mailbox has more messages (1000501) exist than the maximum
> (1000000)

Then I delete some emails in `Gmail` and pull mails successfully, so I guess `IMAP` has a message number limitation, but I can't find any answer via any official documents.

Does anyone know what's going on here? Do you have some other solutions of pulling emails via `IMAP` without deleting original emails from `Gmail`?

Comment: This is a limitation of the UW IMAP libc client library, which PHP depends on for the imap_* functions. Where are you getting the error? On open or search? If the latter, surely you can break down your workload into batches by providing filters to make smaller sets.

Comment: If your folder has over a million messages in it, you are going to have extremely poor performance.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks for your reply! The warning message appeared when we used imap_savebody or imap_num_msg, but I used imap_search and only can get the limitation number 1,000,000.